# configure xdebug debugger so to to debug with netbeans a script started through a web browser

Tags: php, debugging, netbeans

I 'm tring to configure xdebug debugger so to to debug with netbeans a script started through a web browser

scenario

```
mypc localhost
linux ubuntu16.04
apache2.4
php7.2
netbeans8.2 IDE
both script.php and IDE in mypc
```

xdebug configuration

$ sudo nano /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/xdebug.ini

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
;debugger_clients (remote)
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
;xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_connect_back=On
```

$ sudo nano /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini

```
output_buffering=Off
```

$ sudo netstat -ltnp | grep :9000

empty output

netbeansIDE,  Tools > Options > PHP > Debuging >

SessionID:  netbeans-xdebug

DebbuggerPort: 9000

Then I created a netbeans project and configured

if I try to execute script in debug mode from netbeans (click Debug>) 
debugging mode works!!!

instead if I try to execute script in debug mode from web browser then debugging mode doesnt work!!!

http://localhost/path/to/script/index.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug

the script is executed without interruptions!!!

I tried also firefox extension "Xdebug Helper for Firefox" installed but without success

Comment: This isn't a WP question, and belongs on stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

this is due to the fact that netbeans is not always listening

netbeans listens on port 9000 only after you click on the Debug> button

it's not a big limit
that's okay